# Kill a file after running & closing

Tags: file, lotus-notes, delete-file

In my lotusscripy I create an external file, I "print" some lines in it, I close it and then I run it with the Shell function:

```
    Open "D:\testF.dsx" For Output As fileNum%
    Print #fileNum%, "line1"
    Print #fileNum%, "line2"
    Print #fileNum%, "line3"
    Close fileNum%
    result = Shell(|path "D:\testF.dsx"|, 1)
```

The shell function works fine, the file it's running.

After this I just put

```
    Kill fileNum% 'which should delete the file
```

Also, I've tried to add

```
    Sleep 2 'before the Kill statement but I get the same error: Path/file access error.
```

Thanks for your time!

- Another alternative for my script will be to clear all text from the file => so the file will be empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Lotusscript kill statement expects a filename and not a file num. So do this instead:

```
Kill "D:\testF.dsx"
```

Comment: Also note that Shell() will just call the command line and then continue with the next line. If the code is fast enough, the file is deleted before the shell have time to execute it. I would suggest using a ShellAndWait function instead.
From the Domino Designer help: "After Shell starts a program, LotusScript continues to execute the script without waiting to make sure the program has completed. You cannot be sure that a program started by Shell has finished running before the rest of your script is executed."